# How to make a rotating cube move horizontally?

Tags: c++, opengl

I used C++/OpenGL and drew a rotating cube. Now I want to make it move horizontally while it is rotating. I put a line glTranslatef(0.01, 0, 0). It moves horizontally but does not rotate. Following is my code. Any idea how to fix it so that the cube can move horizontally across while it is rotating?

```
   void drawcube(void) {

    int p[][3] = { { 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, -1, 1 }, { -1, -1, 1 }, { -1, 1, 1 },
    { 1, 1, -1 }, { 1, -1, -1 }, { -1, -1, -1 }, { -1, 1, -1 } };

    int e[][4] = { { 0, 3, 2, 1 }, { 3, 7, 6, 2 }, { 7, 4, 5, 6 }, { 4, 0, 1, 5 },
    { 0, 4, 7, 3 }, { 1, 2, 6, 5 } };
    float c[][3] = { { 1.0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 1.0, 0 }, { 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 },{ 0, 0, 1.0 }, { .6, 0, .6 }, { 0, .6, .6 } };
    int i;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glTranslatef(0.01, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(global.angle, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        glColor3fv(c[i]);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex3iv(p[e[i][0]]);
        glVertex3iv(p[e[i][1]]);
        glVertex3iv(p[e[i][2]]);
        glVertex3iv(p[e[i][3]]);
        glEnd();
    }

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```